# SoundCloud API: Is It Possible To Automate Both Uploads & Embed Codes Generation?

Tags: soundcloud

is it possible to complete this 3-step process via the SoundCloud API?

1. programmatically upload a track
2. (also programmatically) immediately generate and receive the embed code for that track
3. (ugggh...also programmatically) use that embed code to embed that track on a dynamically generated web page on our own site that would be dedicated to that clip

If requesting a simple "Yes / No" answer makes this question more likely to get answered....or just less likely to be "closed"....I'd be more than happy with just such an answer.  :-)

CHEERS!

Kirk

Comment: Sounds simple enough. Once you get the `track_url` you can do whatever you want with it on your website.  http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs

Not sure what you mean by programmatically upload a track though. Do you want to allow users who are soundcloud users to be able to upload directly from your website?

Comment: Thank you, @kush. Our users upload spoken word tracks to us, then we do some automated post-production to the tracks and the crux of our hope is that we can then automate the uploading of all our users' tracks to just one (ours) SoundCloud account.

Comment: OK, so that is a bit different than what I was thinking. That sounds so much simpler.

Comment: OK, so that is a bit different than what I was thinking. What you are saying sounds so much simpler. You will just have a bunch of files that you will upload yourself to soundcloud, right? 

The uploading part should be really simple. If you've ever worked with stuff like `iMacros` give that a shot and your interns/minions will hail you. Once you have the properly formatted sounds on your soundcloud, you could pull the url from the rss feed and use that to pro grammatically create pages on your website. http://developers.soundcloud.com/blog/custom-players Thanks for supporting soundcloud!